# How to get below SQL output

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to get select from a table and return row based on values of a column. Below is data and desired output. If column EmpRecord has multiple values not null to be returned, if it has only null then it should be returned.

```
Data Table

EmployeeNo                  EmpRecord
1                           A
1                           NULL
2                           a
3                           NULL
4                           NULL
4                           A
4                           aa




Output
EmployeeNo                  EmpRecord
1                           A
2                           a
3                           NULL
4                           A
4                           aa
```

Any advice on how to go ahead with it would be great?

Regards,
Sid

Comment: You may want to use a correlated subquery with `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half of the `UNION` query below simply strips off records for which the `EmpRecord` be `NULL`.  This *almost* gets the job done, except that for employees who have *only* one more `NULL` records, this would remove them from the result set as well.  So the second part of the `UNION` adds these employees back as a single record with their employee number and `NULL` placeholder for the record.

```
SELECT t1.EmployeeNo,
       t1.EmpRecord
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.EmpRecord IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.EmployeeNo,
       NULL AS EmpRecord
FROM yourTable t2.
GROUP BY t2.EmployeeNo
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t2.EmpRecord IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: @Sid Please try the query again.